# Put Bounty on Answered Question with Wrong Answer

Tags: support, bounties, wrong-answers

[How can I create a custom live tile in Windows Phone 8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858979/how-can-i-create-a-custom-live-tile-in-windows-phone-8-1) is the exact question I want to ask.  The accepted answer is wrong.  So I want to put a bounty on it to bring the attention of someone who provide a correct answer.

How does it work with putting a bounty on someone else's question, specifically if it has already been answered?  Will it just award the bounty to that person who gave the wrong answer, or will it bring some attention for a right answer?

Comment: I read that, @Shadow Wizard.  My answer is not in there.

Comment: Yes it is. The actual support question here is "Will it just award the bounty to that person who gave the wrong answer" and the answer is "no", as the bounty will be auto awarded only to answers posted after you start it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will attract attention. It will be "featured"!
But if no new answers are given after you place the bounty and you don't award it manually, it will not be awarded to any answer and the points will be lost forever.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties